# How to get the removed text when using text-overflow: ellipsis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to know the ellipsized and visible substrings of a string?

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dyfkqhk4/1/

I want to know:

Original Text: `This is some ellipsed text`

Visible Text: `This is`

Ellipsized Text: `some ellipsed text`

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to get this value as the effect is not part of the DOM. Why do you need it?

Comment: ^^ Sounds like an X/Y problem.  If you can explain what you want it for there's probably a solution.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I have a list on the screen, each record is ellipsized, if user searches for a text "abc", and if "abc" is part of ellipsized text, I want to highlight 3dots ... to indicate that searched text is ellipsized.

Answer (score 0):

here's something that is not always so exact but it is close: **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/dyfkqhk4/2/)**

```
$('body').append('<div class="temp-letter">k</div>');
$('.temp-letter').css({
    width:'initial',
    display:'inline-block'
});
var letterWidth=$('.temp-letter').width(),
    index=Math.ceil($('div').width()/letterWidth);
$('.temp-letter').remove();
alert($('div').text().substr(index,$('div').text().length));
```

you can change the width to check the functionality if you want